# How do I fix module 'tensorflow.python.keras.activations' has no attribute 'get' error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, dcgan

I'm trying to make a DCGAN but I keep getting this error when initializing the Convolutional2D layer for my discriminator. It worked fine when I tried it a few days ago but now it's broken.

Here's the build up to the specific layer that is causing problems

```py
i = Input(shape=(90,90,3))
x = Conv2D(265,(5,5),activation = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.02))(i)
```

Comment: Did you try changing the version? if its still broken please share your logs and full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try changing the version? if its still broken please share your logs and full code.

Comment: Try using comments for small queries or when asking for clarification from the question author, instead of posting an answer.

Comment: Thanks. I was using google colab so I didn't think I needed to reinstall. Upon uninstalling and reinstalling tensorflow it worked.